# Lectura de archivo

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy tratando de realizar un programa que lea un archivo de texto, este lo debe de imprimir en pantalla en unos campos definidos, debo de configurar un boton de primero, siguiente, anterior y ultimo. Estoy con el de siguiente pero trato de realizarlo mediante un ciclo como si fuera un array pero no logro que me avance cada vez que presiono el boton.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame v_frame = new JFrame();
    v_frame.setSize(500, 500);
    v_frame.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lb_nombre = new JLabel("Nombre:");
    lb_nombre.setBounds(50, 50, 80, 30);
    v_frame.add(lb_nombre);

    JLabel lb_cedula = new JLabel("Cedula:");
    lb_cedula.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 30);
    v_frame.add(lb_cedula);

    JLabel lb_edad = new JLabel("Edad:");
    lb_edad.setBounds(50, 150, 200, 30);
    v_frame.add(lb_edad);

    v_nombre.setBounds(150, 50, 200, 30);
    v_frame.add(v_nombre);

    v_cedula.setBounds(150, 100, 200, 30);
    v_frame.add(v_cedula);

    v_edad.setBounds(150, 150, 200, 30);
    v_frame.add(v_edad);

    v_modelo.addColumn("Nombre: ");
    v_modelo.addColumn("Cedula: ");
    v_modelo.addColumn("Edad: ");
    v_tabla.setBounds(50, 250, 400, 140);
    v_tabla.setVisible(true);
    v_frame.add(v_tabla);

    JButton bt_salir = new JButton();
    bt_salir.setText("Salir");
    bt_salir.setBounds(400, 400, 80, 30);
    bt_salir.setVisible(true);
    v_frame.add(bt_salir);
    bt_salir.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);

        }
    });

    JButton bt_primero = new JButton();
    bt_primero.setText("Primero");
    bt_primero.setBounds(20, 200, 80, 30);
    bt_primero.setVisible(true);
    v_frame.add(bt_primero);
    bt_primero.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            leer();
            primero(v_modelo);

        }
    });

    JButton bt_Siguiente = new JButton();
    bt_Siguiente.setText("Siguiente");
    bt_Siguiente.setBounds(110, 200, 100, 30);
    bt_Siguiente.setVisible(true);
    v_frame.add(bt_Siguiente);
    bt_Siguiente.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            leer();
            siguiente();

        }
    });

    JButton bt_ante = new JButton();
    bt_ante.setText("Anterior");
    bt_ante.setBounds(220, 200, 100, 30);
    bt_ante.setVisible(true);
    v_frame.add(bt_ante);
    bt_ante.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            leer();

        }
    });

    JButton bt_ulti = new JButton();
    bt_ulti.setText("Ultimo");
    bt_ulti.setBounds(330, 200, 100, 30);
    bt_ulti.setVisible(true);
    v_frame.add(bt_ulti);
    bt_ulti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            leer();

        }
    });

    v_frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Codigo para el boton de siguiente:

```
public static void siguiente() {

    try {
        FileReader v_lector = new FileReader(v_ruta_archivo);
        BufferedReader mi_buffer = new BufferedReader(v_lector);
        String v_linea;
        while ((v_linea = mi_buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            String v_arreglo[] = v_linea.split(",");
            Object[] v_temporal = {v_arreglo[0], v_arreglo[1], v_arreglo[2]};
            int lim = v_arreglo.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < lim - 2; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < i + 1; j++) {
                    String linea1 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    String linea2 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(i, 1);
                    String linea3 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(i, 2);
                    v_nombre.setText(linea1);
                    v_cedula.setText(linea2);
                    v_edad.setText(linea3);

                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Lectura", "Error", 0);
    }
}
}
```

Queria utilizar el archivo como si fuera un arreglo, o tratando de transformarlo de una `JTable` a un `Array` para el manejo, pero estoy perdido, alguna sugerencia por favor.
Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Mi sugerencia seria para leer archivo txt:

```
public Stream<String> leerAchivoExterno(String rutaArchivo) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;

    try {
        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(rutaArchivo), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ArchivoImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

y de aquí lo que puedes hacer es usar el comando split("separador") para tener todos los valores de cada linea del txt y convertirlo en un arreglo. Aquí te dejo un ejm. de otro usuario con una duda parecida.

```
public String[][] texto2arreglo(Stream<String> archivo){
    List<String> textos = archivo.collect(Collectors.toList()); // se convierte el stream en una lista

    int filas = textos.size(); // se obtiene la cantidad de filas necesarias
    int columnas = textos.get(0).split(",").length; // se obtienen las columnas necesarias separando el contenido por las comas

    String arreglo[][] = new String[filas][columnas]; // se establece un arreglo

    IntStream.range(0, filas).forEach(y -> { // se recorre fila a fila del archivo
        String linea = textos.get(y);
        IntStream.range(0, columnas).forEach(x -> { // y por cada fila se recorre el contenido que se encuentra separado por comas correspondiente a cada columna
            arreglo[y][x] = linea.split(",")[x]; // se guarda en el arreglo el contenido que le corresponde en la fila y columna de interes
        });
    });

   return arreglo;
}
```

Comment: Don AndyC, muchas gracias por la colaboracion voy a realizar la prueba y le estare notificando, ya la parte de leer el archivo me funciona bien, es solo al momento de querer identificar el siguiente dato donde me da el problema!

Comment: public static void siguiente() {
        int tam = v_modelo.getDataVector().size();
        int cont = 0;
        if (cont<tam-1) {
            String linea1 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(cont, 0);
            String linea2 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(cont,1);
            String linea3 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(cont, 2);
            v_nombre.setText(linea1);
            v_cedula.setText(linea2);
            v_edad.setText(linea3);
            cont++;
            System.out.println("contador"+cont);
            
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

Buenas encontre otra forma de poder realizar parte de lo que necesito pero tengo otro problema:

```
public static void siguiente() {
    int tam = v_modelo.getDataVector().size();
    int cont = 0;
    if (cont<tam-1) {
        String linea1 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(cont, 0);
        String linea2 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(cont,1);
        String linea3 = (String) v_modelo.getValueAt(cont, 2);
        v_nombre.setText(linea1);
        v_cedula.setText(linea2);
        v_edad.setText(linea3);
        cont++;
        System.out.println("contador"+cont);

        }
    }
}
```

de aca me brinca de un solo al ultimo valor y no me lo da de uno en uno como lo necesito. Me gustaría saber como solventar este algoritmo
Ayuda Pls

Comment: Ya entiendo lo que quieres hacer pero tu codigo necesita ser desacoplado mejor y separar la vista de la logica. Te sugiero que revises para empezar el MVC(modelo-vista-controlador). En tu codigo necesitas que esa variable que usas como contador sea global para guardar el status del recorrido porque por lo que interpreto le das siguiente y se deberia mostrar el contenido de la tabla en los textfield. Ademas te sugiero revisar DefaultTableModel para evitar que ya no hallan mas datos que se puedan recorrer tanto en siguiente como atras. Cualquier otra duda sigue preguntando